Swiper JS - Animate nested elements when slider is loaded
I am using Swiper js to create a slider and I want to animate the nested elements (such as the slide title + description + button).
I see that swiper supports parallax transition effects for nested elements (https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parallax). So adding 'data-swiper-parallax' attributes to the nested elements. It works, but only when it transitions to the next/previous slide. Currently, on my slider, when it's loaded, the nested elements are just static. I want those to play the animation on the first slide when the slider is loaded.
I was thinking of using the 'on' method and 'init' (https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events) to play the animations, but I can't seem to find a way to play those 'data-swiper-parallax' animations.

Could you show your code so far?
